# React unit test with jest in es6

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, reactjs

I am pretty new in react world and trying to write simple friendslist application. I wrote my friends store in es6 style and using babel as transpiler from es5 to es6.

```
import AppDispatcher from '../dispatcher/app_dispatcher';
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
import FRIENDS_CONST from '../constants/friends';

const CHANGE_EVENT = 'CHANGE';

let friendsList = [];


let add = (name) => {

    let counter = friendsList.length + 1;
    let newFriend = {
        id: counter,
        name: name
    };

    friendsList.push(newFriend);

}

let remove = (id) => {
    let index = friendsList.findIndex(e => e.id == id);
    delete friendsList[index];
}


let FriendsStore = Object.assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {

    getAll: () => {
        return friendsList;
    },

    emitChange: () => {
        this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
    },

    addChangeListener: (callback) => {
        this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
    },

    removeChangeListener: (callback) => {
        this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
    }

});

AppDispatcher.register((action) => {

    switch (action.actionType) {
        case FRIENDS_CONST.ADD_FRIENDS:
            add(action.name);
            FriendsStore.emitChange();
            break;
        case FRIENDS_CONST.REMOVE_FRIENDS:
            remove(action.id);
            FriendsStore.emitChange();
            break;
    }

});

export default FriendsStore;
```

Now I want to test my store and wrote the unit test also in es6

```
jest.dontMock('../../constants/friends');
jest.dontMock('../friends_store');


describe('FriendsStore', () => {

    import FRIENDS from '../../constants/friends';
    import AppDispatcher from '../../dispatcher/AppDispatcher';
    import FriendsStore from '../friends_store';

    let FakeAppDispatcher;
    let FakeFriendsStore;
    let callback;

    let addFriends = {
        actionType: FRIENDS.ADD_FRIENDS,
        name: 'Many'
    };

    let removeFriend = {
        actionType: FRIENDS.REMOVE_FRIENDS,
        id: '3'
    };

    beforeEach(function() {
        FakeAppDispatcher = AppDispatcher;
        FakeFriendsStore = FriendsStore;
        callback = AppDispatcher.register.mock.calls[0][0];
    });

    it('Should initialize with no friends items', function() {
        var all = FriendsStore.getAll();
        expect(all).toEqual([]);
    });



});
```

When I execute the test with statement `npm test`, I've got the error message:

```
> react-starterify@0.0.9 test /Volumes/Developer/reactjs/app5
> echo "Error: no test specified"

Error: no test specified
```

What am I doing wrong? The file structure looks as follow:
[image]

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with what `react-starterify` is doing, but you might check out [babel-jest](https://github.com/babel/babel-jest), which will expect your tests to be in es6 as well.

Comment: Peruse the jest repo right now and you'll find a fair few open issues related to ES6, Babel and newer versions of node (>0.10.x). It all seems quite broken right now, give them a few months to catch up :S

Comment: I have found that it's easier to go piece together a karma+jasmine system than use Jest even now.

Comment: babel-jest was moved into the Jest repository. The source code can be found in packages/babel-jest. babel-jest is now automatically loaded by Jest and fully integrated.

[source](https://github.com/babel/babel-jest)

Answer (score 3):

I did it following the tutorial:

```
npm install --save-dev jest babel-jest babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react react-test-renderer
```

then

add to package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testPathDirs": [
      "src/main/resources/web_pages/__tests__"
    ]
  },
```

Result:

```
 PASS  src/main/resources/web_pages/__tests__/modules/utils/ValidationUtil.spec.js (5.214s)
  ✓ ValidateEmail (5ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.092s, estimated 7s
Ran all test suites.
```

Answer (score 2):

To test ES6 syntax and JSX files, they need to be transformed for Jest. Jest has a config variable where you can define a preprocessor (scriptPreprocessor).  You can use the [babel-jest](https://github.com/babel/babel-jest) preprocessor:

*Make the following changes to package.json:*

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "*",
    "jest-cli": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
    "testFileExtensions": ["es6", "js"],
    "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "es6"]
  }
}
```

*And run:*

`$ npm install`

Comment: This should be updated to only adding under "jest": { "transform": {".*": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"} }. "scriptPreprocessor" is deprecated.

Comment: Note that, in current Jest versions, babel-jest should be automatically enabled as long as it's installed. See https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/getting-started.html#using-babel and https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/packages/babel-jest.